# 250 users hitting around 60k overall requests in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I have 250 users ,and around 60000 sample counts should be hit including all the requests. Whichever request is supposed to get huge sample count,I have put those request within loop count,But the requests outside the loop are getting executed only 3-4 times which is less than expected. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not very possible to provide the comprehensive answer without knowing what you're trying to achieve and seeing your test or at least Thread Group configuration

1. The easiest option is moving the requests which you want to execute more times into a separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. If the requests have to stay in one Thread Group you can control the frequency using [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
3. If the logic is more complex - consider using [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) or [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide)